# Iterative exponential curve generation for ADSR envelopes

Tags: algorithm, math, exponential, iteration

I am using a book to learn how to generate audio from code. I am having difficulty understanding a part of it. The chapter I am reading talks about iteratively generating ADSR envelopes with exponential attack, decay, and release. It first has an algorithm for the equation:
[image: Equation1]

but suffice it to say that the author explains that this requires the pow() function for each sample in the ADSR curve, which is inefficient. He then continues with a different method as explained in this excerpt:
[image: Equation2]

My first problem is with this set of equations. It seems like the second line is wrong and should read y(n) = b * y(n-1) but the book has no errata so it is hard to be sure. If I am wrong please explain why. Secondly it would appear that y(0) is always 1 when c is 0 in eq 6.7. This makes it confusing to include in the equations in this section because without it you can easily see that b = y(k)^(1/k). I assume that y(0) is included for the next excerpt which is the part of the book with which I truly struggle:
[image: Equation3]

I understand the first paragraph. I understand the first two equations that explain the curve. What I don't understand is how he got that last equation which solves for b. The algorithm hinges on that equation as it allows you to use the pow() function once to calculate b from the desired min value y(0) = 0 and max value y(k) = 1 that you want and use an iterative multiply to calculate each sample of the ADSR curve as is found in the pseudocode:

```
expMin = 0.2; // adjust to change curvature
expMul = pow((expMin+1)/expMin, 1/attackTime);
expNow = expMin;
for (n = 0; n < totalSamples; n++) {
    if (n < attackTime || n > decayStart) {
        expNow *= expMul;
        volume = (expNow – expMin) * peakAmp;
    } else if (n == attackTime) {
        volume = peakAmp;
    } else if (n == decayStart) {
        expNow = 1+expMin;
        expMul = pow(expMin/(1+expMin),1/decayTime));
    }
    sample[n] = volume * sin(phase);
    if ((phase += phaseIncr) >= twoPI)
        phase -= twoPI;
}
```

I know this may not be the best place for this question, but I have been racking my brain and googling for many hours and can't figure it out and don't know where else would be better to ask. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar question here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2555/help-with-equations-for-exponential-adsr-envelope This seems like a great forum, i just found it. You can also ask on KVR DSP forum and native reaktor builders forum and cycling 74 forums